# Filter Google Cloud Datastore entities by @id property in App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, objectify, google-cloud-datastore

I am trying to to a Query in `App Engine` based on the `@id` property of the entities and I keep getting this error

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: __ key __ filter value must be a Key

this is how I am doing my Query

```
Filter f1 = new FilterPredicate("personId", FilterOperator.EQUAL,personId);
Filter f2 = new FilterPredicate(Entity.KEY_RESERVED_PROPERTY, FilterOperator.GREATER_THAN,newestCommentId);

Filter filter = CompositeFilterOperator.and(f1,f2);


Query<Record> query = ofy().load().type(Record.class).filter(filter)
                .limit(limit).order("-"+ Entity.KEY_RESERVED_PROPERTY);
```

I want to get everything `>` the last comment id that is sent to the app engine method

the id field in the entity is this

```
@Id
Long id;
```

I tried using the `id` first but then I got an error saying that you cannot use a file who has @id and maybe I meant __ key __

so how do I execute this query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [use a Key](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries#Java_Key_filters), not an id, in your filter. You can create a Key from this id and then pass to your filter.

Note that unless you increment IDs yourself, they are not guaranteed to grow as you add more entities.

Comment: so an id is unique but not necessarily in order like it would with SQL primary key?